# Why does tzinfo break creating an epoch time in python?

Tags: python, datetime, utc, epoch, pytz

Why does the following happen?

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

d = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())
print float(d.strftime('%s')) - float(d.replace(tzinfo=None).strftime('%s')) # 3600.0
```

Why is it off by one hour whether or not tzinfo is included?  I'm assuming it has to do with DST, but... UTC does not have DST.

```
d.timetuple()
# time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=21, tm_hour=17, tm_min=44, tm_sec=40, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=294, tm_isdst=0)
d.replace(tzinfo=None).timetuple()
# time.struct_time(tm_year=2013, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=21, tm_hour=17, tm_min=44, tm_sec=40, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=294, tm_isdst=-1)
```

So, the difference is `tm_isdst` is `0` or `-1`.  Both seem very "No DST-ish".

Just not thrilled with the workaround.

**Update:**

After reading some docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.mktime)  It appears  `mktime()` outputs "localtime" not UTC as I had thought.  Which confuses everything.

Comment: your title mentions *"epoch time"*. This answer shows [how to convert datetime.date and datatime.datetime to POSIX timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

Answer (score 0):

[`.strftime('%s')` is not supported by Python](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). Do not use it.

On systems where it works, it interprets the datetime object as time in local timezone i.e., `datetime.now().strftime('%s')` might return value near `time.time()`.

To find out utc offset or whether DST is in effect for a given local time, you could call `d.utcoffset()`, `d.dst()` where `d` is a datetime object with pytz timezone.

```
>>> import pytz
>>> d = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
>>> d.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(0)
>>> d.dst()
datetime.timedelta(0)
```

As expected UTC offset is zero for UTC timezone and there is no DST transitions so `.dst()` is always zero all year round.